# Why {} is used in this statement for instantiation, Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Collection<Integer>>(){}.getType();

Tags: java, initialization, json-deserialization

Please explain why `{}` used in

```
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Collection<Integer>>(){}.getType();
```

This is from Gson documentation [link to documentation](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#collections-examples)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's creating a new anonymous type. This is a workaround for type erasure, because you can get the `Collection<Integer>` reflectively via [`Class.getGenericSuperclass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getGenericSuperclass--) and `Class.getGenericInterfaces()` if the class is not generic (*).

This code basically implements the same functionality [<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/luG7zg):

```
abstract class TypeToken<T> {
  Type getType() {
    ParameterizedType t = (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
    return t.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
  }
}

public static void main (String[] args) {
    Collection<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.println(list.getClass().getGenericInterfaces()[0]);

    TypeToken<Collection<Integer>> tt = new TypeToken<Collection<Integer>>() {};

    System.out.println(tt.getClass().getGenericSuperclass());
    System.out.println(tt.getType());
}
```

Output:

```
java.util.List<E>
Ideone.Ideone$TypeToken<java.util.Collection<java.lang.Integer>>
java.util.Collection<java.lang.Integer>
```

You can see that the "Integer"-ness of the `Collection` is lost; but it's still present in the `TypeToken`, so you can get it via the `getType()` method.

---

(*) An important point here is that you can't (correctly) create a `TypeToken` in a generic method. For example:

```
<T> TypeToken<T> getGenericToken() {
  return new TypeToken<T>() {};
}
```

won't work like you might expect [<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/tKWzv6).

```
TypeToken<Collection<String>> t = getGenericToken();
System.out.println(t.getType()); // T, not Collection<String>.
```